# MacVim - executing a shell script not working..?

Tags: shell, macvim

I have written a custom shell script function, and put in in my `.profile`.

When I run the command that executes the function from my terminal, it works just fine, however when I run the command from MacVim, it does nothing. The function in my `.profile` is not being run when I run the command from Macvim.

How to I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your function in `~/.bashrc`. That's for interactive non-login shells.